# How do you use the Django timezone.override(utc) to create datetimes with tzinfo?

Tags: python-3.x, django, datetime, timezone

I can use `timezone.now()` to get a UTC timestamp in Django.
I can use `timezone.make_aware(datetime(2012,1,1))` to add UTC as the TZ for the datetime.

Last one is cumbersome and a lot of extra typing.

Meanwhile I find these docs:  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/i18n/timezones/

But activating the TZ doesn't seem to affect datetime creation (still no tzinfo included)

I also found these docs inside python:

```
>>> from django.utils import timezone
>>> help(timezone)
Help on module django.utils.timezone in django.utils:

NAME
    django.utils.timezone - Timezone-related classes and functions.

CLASSES
    contextlib.ContextDecorator(builtins.object)
        override

    class override(contextlib.ContextDecorator)
     |  override(timezone)
     |
     |  Temporarily set the time zone for the current thread.
     |
     |  This is a context manager that uses django.utils.timezone.activate()
     |  to set the timezone on entry and restores the previously active timezone
     |  on exit.
     |
     |  The ``timezone`` argument must be an instance of a ``tzinfo`` subclass, a
     |  time zone name, or ``None``. If it is ``None``, Django enables the default
     |  time zone.
     |
     |  Method resolution order:
     |      override
     |      contextlib.ContextDecorator
     |      builtins.object
     |
     |  Methods defined here:
     |
     |  __enter__(self)
     |
     |  __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, traceback)
     |
     |  __init__(self, timezone)
     |      Initialize self.  See help(type(self)) for accurate signature.
     |
     |  ----------------------------------------------------------------------
     |  Methods inherited from contextlib.ContextDecorator:
     |
     |  __call__(self, func)
     |      Call self as a function.
     |
     |  ----------------------------------------------------------------------
     |  Data descriptors inherited from contextlib.ContextDecorator:
```

I'm wanting to do something like:

```
from datetime import datetime
from django.utils import timezone

>>> with timezone.override(None):
...   datetime.now()
...
datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 12, 16, 56, 3, 679319). #WTF is the timezone info?
>>>
```

Am I stuck with writing a wrapper class to apply the tzinfo or is there a pythonic way to do this?

Comment: "*If it is ``None``, Django enables the default time zone.*" - so what is your default time zone?

Comment: Default timezone is UTC, but the postgres adapter does not care for Naive datetime objects and warns profusely about them during tests.  I'm wanting something that effectively monkey patches datetime to add the UTC tz for all datetimes that are created.  We do all TZ correction in the client based on the browser to present localtimes.